# The space $c_{00}$ is not a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have to prove that

$$c_{00} = \big\{\: \{x_j\}_{j \in N} \mid x_j = 0 ~\text{eventually} \: \big\} = \operatorname{span}\big\{\:e_j \mid j \in N \:\big\}$$

is not a Hilbert space w.r.t an inner product.

So just to recall the definition of a Hilbert space:

An inner product space is called a Hilbert space if it is complete w.r.t the metric induced by the inner product.

This means, that each Cauchy sequence converges w.r.t the inner product.

So basically what I have to show is that in $c_{00}$ not every Cauchy sequence converges ?

$c_{00}$ is a subspace of $l^2$

Comment: As a first step, you should tell us which inner product you are working with on $c_{00}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(the question was edited after I answered. I'm leaving the more general original answer at the bottom)*

As a subspace of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, the subspace $c_{00}$ is not complete. This is easily seen by considering the sequence $\{x_n\}$, where
$$
x_n=(1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots,\frac1n,0,0,\ldots).
$$
Then $\{x_n\}$ Cauchy, but the limit of the sequence is not in $c_{00}$.

Another possibility is to show that $c_{00}$ is dense.

---

*(original answer)*

The answer to this depends a bit on how the problem is presented to you.

Usually $c_{00}$ is canonically understood as a subspace of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, so the norm is
$$
\|x\|_\infty=\max\{|x_n|:\ n\}. 
$$
In this situation is is trivial to check that the infinity norm does not satisfy the parallelogram identity, so it cannot possibly come from an inner product. Indeed, if $\{e_n\}$ denotes the canonical basis,
$$
\|e_1+e_2\|^2+\|e_1-e_2\|^2=1+1=2\ne 4=2\|e_1\|^2+2\|e_2\|^2. 
$$

More substantially, $c_{00}$ cannot be a Banach space, let alone a Hilbert space, in any norm. The reason is that $c_{00}$ has a countable basis; namely, any $x\in c_{00}$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of the canonical basis. Meanwhile, a consequence of Baire's Categoty Theorem is that a Banach space cannot have a countable basis.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part. $c_{00}$ is a subspace of $l^2$

Comment: Ok, then the answer is much much simpler. I have edited that in .

Comment: Why is the limit of your given sequence not in $c_{00}$? The limit is $0$ and $0$ is in $c_{00}$

Comment: No, the limit is not $0$.

Comment: What else could be the limit? $1/n$ goes to 0 as $n\to \infty$

Comment: With what metric? You think the elements of $c_{00}$ are numbers?

Comment: The elements of $c_{00}$ are sequences of numbers. And $l_2 = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty$
But because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n \to \infty$ I don't understand your point. The sum of 1/n doesn't converge.

Comment: You need to stop, and write carefully what the metric is, and then calculate if the sequence is Cauchy or not.